# CSV reading - Filter of the date doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have such problem. I have csv file: [NEW_YORK_NYPD.csv](http://sigmaquality.pl/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/NEW_YORK_NYPD.csv)
I need date format in this two columns.
Whay it this condition doesn't work?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('c:/1/NEW_YORK_NYPD.csv', low_memory=False, parse_dates=[1,2] )
## I once again make date format to be sure its work!
pd.to_datetime(df['Created Date'], errors='coerce', format='%Y-%m-%d HH:mm:ss')

df.to_csv('c:/1/NY20_NYPD.csv')     #<-- Save effect
df.to_excel('c:/1/NY20_NYPD.xlsx')
```

Date processor doesn't work. What is interesting in Excel I have format data.
I checked CSV - I have no date format!

```
aa = pd.read_csv('c:/1/NY20_NYPD.csv')
print(aa.dtypes)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working set first column to index, so need `parse_dates=[2,3]` for parse 3. and 4. column (python counts from 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv('NEW_YORK_NYPD.csv', low_memory=False, parse_dates=[2,3], index_col=0)
print (df.head())

print (df.dtypes.head())
Unique Key               int64
Created Date    datetime64[ns]
Closed Date     datetime64[ns]
Agency                  object
Agency Name             object
dtype: object
```

But if save columns to csv again is necessary converting to datetimes, because by default `read_csv` not converting columns with no parameter `parse_dates`.